# How to make flutter platform view background transparent on android tv

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show a widget from native and make the Android view background transparent, i tried on mobile device and it works fine, but when run on android tv marshmallow    6.0 API level 23, the background is always black. I am using flutter 1.22.6